# Restrict access to static resource on nginx behind alteon

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, whitelist

I have nginx with two resources `/public_url` and `/private_url` behind Alteon load balancer. I can restrict access to `private_url` using `nginx.conf`:

```
location /private_url {
  include whitelist.conf; 
  deny all;
}
```

Note that `public_url` remains available from any IP aadd

This works when I access nginx directly. However, when I access nginx through Alteon I can only see Alteon's IP address. As a result, I cannot distinguish whitelisted and blacklisted IP addresses.

What is the right way to organize IP filtering to `private_url`, but serve `public_url` to everyone when nginx is behind alteon?

Answer (score 2):

A load balancer by default removes all of the client's headers when passing the request to an upstream. Including the ip address and replacing it with the server's ip. 
 In nginx as a load balancer you would add `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;`. I'm not sure about Alteon but I found this link explaining how to achieve that: https://support.radware.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/15085/~/how-to-insert-x-forwarded-header-for-piped-server-load-balanced-traffic-to-real